# How can I find out what version of SharePoint search is being used in the farm?

Tags: 2010, search

How can I find out what version of SharePoint search is being used in the farm? I know there are a few out there, ex:

- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Search
- Microsoft Search Server Express
- Microsoft Search Server 2010
- Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 then you will have SharePoint Foundation Search available with basic search capability like site search. If you install Search Server Express 2010 in SharePoint Foundation then you can create Search Service Application in Central Administration and can configure all those configuration and customization that you can do in Enterprise Search 2010.

SharePoint Server 2010 will have Enterprise search capabilities but the features may be less or more depending on what edition you install - Standard or Enterprise.

If you want to see the versions of search you use, simply look into Start -> Administrative Tools -> Service.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in Central Administration > Application Management > System Settings > Manage server in this farm. Another way could be to look in Programs and Feature in the control panel to see what is installed.